# Close a socket without FD_CLR

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Should applications use `FD_CLR()` before `close()` of a socket descriptor?

Does shutdown take care of `FD_CLR()`? Sometimes I observe that `close()` works even without `FD_CLR()` but sometimes the socket still shows up in the netstat entries.

Why is this erratic?

Answer (score 1):

> Should applications use FD_CLR() before close() of a socket descriptor?

You should certainly use `FD_CLR` if you're going to keep using that `fd_set` after closing the socket.

> Does shutdown take care of FD_CLR()?

No.

> Sometimes I observe that close() works even without FD_CLR() but sometimes the socket still shows up in the netstat entries.

Shows up how? And `FD_CLR` doesn't have anything to do with ports remaining in `TIME-WAIT` or other states in `netstat`.

You seem to be asking  three questions at once.

Comment: Was debugging an issue where close() is called w/o FD_CLR() but the connection is still alive on server listening port. I then tried FD_CLR() before close () and still the issue is there. I am using netstat to see that the connection is still alive. However, shutdown() seems to work. Could this be a bug ? The OS is monta-vista linux (an older version)

Comment: So in other words the problem had nothing to do with `FD_CLR`. You proved it. `shutdown()` with `SHUT_WR` is equivalent to `close()` from the peer's point of view: it will receive an end of stream, whereupon it should close the socket (unless it knows somehow that the peer shutdown, in which case it may keep sending, but that isn't the case under discussion here). What is the *actual problem* you're trying to solve? `TIME_WAIT`? - just wait. `CLOSE_WAIT`? - the local application where you ran `netstat` isn't closing the socket.